# Python numpy mask disappears after assigning array to another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

So I am working with geodetical data and use masks to cover areas without data.
Here I have just run into the problem of trying to design an array with different time series data of different spots on earth. The actual problem is only that when I assign my seperate spot arrays to the bigger array, the masks disappear without me being able to even reassign the masks.

I create an array and load the data (daily data of a 1° grid, excluding the southernmost 30°) and transpose it so that i can look at different spots easily:

```
minmax_0_10T = np.ma.zeros((2,360,150,365))
with np.load("Data/Pythonarrays/1DEG_SM_minmax_SWI_001_SM0_10cm_2015.npz") as npz:
    minmax_0_10T[0] = np.ma.MaskedArray(**npz).T
with np.load("Data/Pythonarrays/1DEG_SM_minmax_SWI_005_SM0_10cm_2015.npz") as npz:
    minmax_0_10T[1] = np.ma.MaskedArray(**npz).T
```

I have 2 datasets I want to plot and 4 different spots i want to look at

```
spots_1deg = [[41, 210], [29, 119], [108, 196], [117, 256]]
minmax_0_10_spots = np.ma.zeros((2,4,365))
"""Create array of minmax and gldas spotdata for choice of SWI layer"""
for i in range(len(spots_1deg)):
    for layer_gldas in range(len(gldas_smT)):
        gldas_spots[layer_gldas][i] = gldas_smT[layer_gldas][spots_1deg[i][1]][spots_1deg[i][0]]
        
    """now all different gldas layers of minmax fitting"""
    minmax_0_10_spots[0][i] = minmax_0_10T[0][spots_1deg[i][1]][spots_1deg[i][0]]
    minmax_0_10_spots[1][i] = minmax_0_10T[1][spots_1deg[i][1]][spots_1deg[i][0]]
```

however if I then compare `minmax_0_10T[0][spots_1deg[i][1]][spots_1deg[i][0]]` with `minmax_0_10_spots[0][i]` directly, i see that the `minmax_0_10_spots` array does not contain the mask anymore (as in the mask is `False` everywhere). How and why is this happening? Assigning the masks each also did not work, in the end I had to define `minmax_0_10_spots` as list and filling it as such, however also there cannot tranform it into an array, cause that makes the masks disappear.

I have tried to look into the np.ma documentation but I must have either overread something or not understood...

It all boils down to the following problem:
If I have my 3 dimensional array the mask is not transferred to the array:

```
array = np.ma.zeros((2,4,4))
data = np.ma.array(data=[0,0,5.435,3.657], mask =[True,True,False,False],fill_value=1e+20)
array[0][0] = data
data2 = array[0][0]
now data2 does not contain the mask anymore.
```

However if i remove 1 dimension the mask is transferred:

```
array = np.ma.zeros((2,4))
data = np.ma.array(data=[0,0,5.435,3.657], mask =[True,True,False,False],fill_value=1e+20)
array[0] = data
data2 = array[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [11]: array = np.ma.zeros((2,4,4))
    ...: data = np.ma.array(data=[0,0,5.435,3.657], mask =[True,True,False,False],fill_value=1e+20)
```

Your assignment:

```
In [12]: array[0][0]=data

In [13]: array
Out[13]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[[0.   , 0.   , 5.435, 3.657],
         [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
         [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
         [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ]],

        [[0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
         [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
         [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
         [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ]]],
  mask=False,
  fill_value=1e+20)
```

Better assignment:

```
In [14]: array[0,0]=data

In [15]: array
Out[15]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[[--, --, 5.435, 3.657],
         [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
         [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
         [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],

        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
         [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
         [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
         [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]],
  mask=[[[ True,  True, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False]],

        [[False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False]]],
  fill_value=1e+20)
```

Normally `a[0,0]=...` and `a[0][0]=...` do the same thing.  But apparently `np.ma` indexing has a flaw, and the mask doesn't carry through in the two stage indexing.

`a[0][0]=...` does `temp=a[0]; temp[0]=....`.  That works if `temp` is a (normal) `view`.  It does not work if `temp` is a copy (as with advanced indexing).  For MaskedArrays, `a[0]` is not a `view` (as it would be for a regular `ndarray`).

In short, it's best to use `a[0,0]` style of indexing, especially when doing assignment.

Answer (score 0):

With the arrays coming from `load` I can't test your code.  It would be easier if you constructed something much small - that can be copy-n-pasted.

Here's a simple test on 1d arrays:

```
In [8]: m = np.ma.zeros(5)
In [9]: m
Out[9]: 
masked_array(data=[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
             mask=False,
       fill_value=1e+20)

In [11]: m1 = np.ma.masked_array(np.arange(5),[1,0,1,0,1])
In [12]: m1
Out[12]: 
masked_array(data=[--, 1, --, 3, --],
             mask=[ True, False,  True, False,  True],
       fill_value=999999)
In [13]: for i in range(5):m[i]=m1[i]
In [14]: m
Out[14]: 
masked_array(data=[--, 1.0, --, 3.0, --],
             mask=[ True, False,  True, False,  True],
       fill_value=1e+20)
```

Comment: Ah of course my mistake i will put a test you can do in my question!